# Boost Volume in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Hi I am using `MPMoviePlayerController` to play a movie in my app. My client wants to boost the audio of the movie that should be greater than `iOS` system max volume. How to achieve this?

Comment: Boost the volume in the original video with any video editting program...

Comment: But in my app the user can select any video from photo library. I want to boost the volume within my code.

Answer (score 2):

It's impossible to boost volume higher than iOS default settings.

Answer (score 0):

If your client wants louder audio in a video, get them to edit the video content and up the volume of the video's audio (in the case that their video sound is very low). 
For example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvLgQ61wJS8

For iOS, the device user is in control of the volume, you cannot apply sound volume larger than their defined volume or any volume at all if the device is muted.